# calculate the sum of a series with limit of x tends to 1

Tags: math

I want to calculate the sum of the series as below
Lim
X->1 (2/3 - x/3 -(x^2)/3 +(x^3)*2/3 -..).  I am not sure whether we have a formula for finding the sum of this kind of series. Tried a lot but couldn't find any. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be more maths than computing.

It factorises as (1 + *x*^3 + *x*^6 + ...)(2 - *x* - *x*^2)/3

If *x* = 1-*d* (where *d* is small), then to first order in *d*, the (2 - *x* - *x*^2) term becomes (2 - (1-*d*) - (1-2*d*)) = 3*d*

And the (1 + *x*^3 + *x*^6 + ...) term is a geometric progression, with sum 1/(1-*x*^3), or here 1/(1-(1-*d*)^3), and the denominator to first order in *d* is (1 - (1-3*d*)) = 3*d*

Hence the whole thing is (1/3*d*) (3*d*) / 3 = 1/3

But we can also verify computationally with a value close to 1 (Python code here):

```
x = 0.999999
s = 0

f = (2 - x - x*x) / 3.
x3 = x ** 3

s_prev = None
while s != s_prev:
    s_prev = s
    s += f
    f *= x3
    
print(s)
```

gives:

```
0.33333355556918565
```